# I am able to add composite indexes to index.yaml file and get it to work without removing and reloading the data from datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I thought that this was not possible and that you had to reload all the data if you added new indexes.

Is this supposed to happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Cloud Datastore [builds a new index](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/indexconfig#Datastore_Updating_indexes), it includes any existing entities that match the index, so there's no need to update your existing data.

If, however, you have inserted entities with [*unindexed* properties](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes#unindexed_properties) and decide you want to define indexes on those properties, then you need to update each of those entities to mark the property as indexed.

Comment: What if my entities consists of 5 properties, A,B,C,D and E and I make an index with A B and C. Then I realize that I also want an index with B D and E. Will this work without purging and re uploading the data?

Comment: As long as you didn't exclude B, D, or E from indexing when the entities were originally written, then you won't need to explicitly update the entities.